# Magento Product Image URL

Tags: product, product-images, magento2.2.3

In Magento 2.2.3, I am using the following for loop to get the product image. When I print that image url, it takes the previous product's URL actually it doesnt have the URL.

```
 $products = $this->getCollection ();
    foreach ( $products as $product ) {

        $preImageUrl = $product->getImage ();
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer and upvote accept if it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get full image path of product using this code :

```
protected $_product;
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
 ...
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
 ...
)
{
...
$this->_product = $product;
$this->$_storeManager = $storeManager;
...
}

public function execute(){
    $product = $this->_product->load('product_id');
    $mediaPath = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $product_image_full_path =  $mediaPath . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
}
```

Hope, it will useful for you !!

Comment: hi @Rohan, this will return the product image without cache, same image how can we load in list page, default magento category page loads images with cache folder